# Wiggle me when you want to find me

Tags: riddle

Wiggle me when you want to find me 
Pay attention to what's behind me 
I'm an extension of your will 
I can act, but I cannot feel

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

> A mouse (pointer).

Some explanation:

> 1. "Wiggle me when you want to find me"  -  When you want to find your mouse pointer on the screen, you wiggle the mouse in your hand.
>
>  2. "Pay attention to what's behind me" - Whatever is behind the pointer is what you activate when you click.
>
>  3. "I'm an extension of your will" - A mouse is an input device, to exercise your will on the computer.
>
>  4. "I can act, but I cannot feel" - The mouse pointer 'acts' by clicking and moving, but has no 'feelings' as such.  The mouse in your hand only senses movement.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! That seems like a good answer and thank you for putting it behind spoiler tags. However, it's often helpful to explain your reasoning (either overall reasoning or line-by-line).

Answer (score 5):

Is it:

> A mouse pointer

Wiggle me when you want to find me

> To find it, most people wiggle it so its movement is caught and the pointer is located

Pay attention to what's behind me

> You need to pay attention to the web page or at least what's on the computer screen

I'm an extension of your will

> People can use this external device willingly and how they want to willingly and force the pointer to do what the person does willingly

I can act, but I cannot feel

> You are an object that can highlight, click, select and do lots of stuff but you can't express emotion

Comment: Nice job for being first to answer correctly, but I decided to accept Solocutor's answer since his explanation was a bit more accurate.

Comment: Wait, I'm an object with no emotions?!?! :(

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> A loose tooth.  Its got the wiggling down, and you know it's there when it does.  When it wiggles the nerves behind it in your gums will get your attention.  Its an outgrowth of your head, the seat of your will. The nerve in the tooth itself are disconnected, but you could still chew, gently, with the tooth.

Comment: Very nice alternative, but I'd say the 4th clue is not as fitting.